# Can not run CastleWinsord

Tags: .net

I create a simple IOC Sample project with CastleWinsor. I put this configSession in App.config file.

```
  <configSections>
<section
    name="castle"
    type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor" />
```

The Error happened in Mail function at line:

```
IWindsorContainer container =new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("castle")));
```

Error Message is: **Configuration system failed to initialize**
I watch the ConfigResource("castle") and see that: 
**'Castle.Core.Resource.ConfigResource' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'**

Would you like to help me? 
Thanks alot

Comment: Are you sure your app.config is well formed?  You left the closing tag off of `<configSecitions>`

Comment: Also your watch window problem is a red herring.  Adding a watch on `ConfigResource("castle")` instead of `new ConfigResource("castle")` will give you that error message.